# PHP: Differences in parsing static file and php array file

Tags: php, arrays, parsing, translation

I wanted to find best way to make translation framework (gettext have some imperfections).

So I make two tests - One, **parsing** file contains static text by code below

```
function parseLine($line) {
    if($line[0] == '#' || !strlen($line)) 
        return array();

    $eq = strpos($line, '=');
    $key = trim(substr($line, 0, $eq));

    $value = trim(substr($line, $eq+1));
    $value = trim($value, '"');

    return array($key => $value);
}

$table = array();
$fp = fopen('lang.lng', 'r');
while(!feof($fp)) {
    $table += parseLine(fgets($fp, 4096));
}
fclose($fp);
```

and secondly **including array**

```
$table = include('lang.php');
```

Of course each lang.lng and lang.php has same data (1000 records) but reperesented in diffrent way.

I was surpised when I saw results...
**First method**: ~0.01 s
**Second**: ~0.001 s

Before test I was sure that including array will take more memory and time then parsing file.
Could somebody explain me where is mistake?

Comment: '$table += ', You dont add more elements to a PHP array like that

Comment: there's no mistake. It is as it should be.

Comment: Hanky Panky ㇱ you are wrong
@Vlad Balmos but I was thinking that parsing php file will take more time.. each line (each char) mustbe tested becouse it can contain special things

Comment: If you used something less quirky for extracting the text (like a single regex) the comparison would make sense. Anyhow, use a profiler; nobody else can tell.

Comment: @non Its veryyyyyy interesting that you should say i am wrong in saying that += is an incorrect operator to add new elements to a PHP array, and its even more interesting that someone upvoted that comment. This is the first time i have seen that and it does not work, fyi.

Comment: "gettext have some imperfections" - I would work with these imperfections rather than inventing own framework. Gettext has two decades of polishing and a large ecosystem. You get string extracting for free (xgettext) and PHP works with compiled files (*.mo) very fast.

Comment: @HankyPankyㇱ it works
http://pics.tinypic.pl/i/00260/k7vrt9dx06lg.jpg

Comment: gettext has strange and uncomfortable syntax

Comment: The problem is that you're trying to reinvent something that is already here (and perfectly fine) instead of creating real value for your customer. Go with gettext, trust me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would have thought that was a no-brainer. Which is faster, reading in a file that contains an array, or reading in a file, processing it line-by-line, and for each line look for various tokens and components and piece them all together in a complex matter to result in the same array as the include method?

Comment: each line of array can contain comment / function / constant etc.
in my method there are only comments and varibles

Comment: and php array file also have to be processed line-by-line sooo??

Comment: Yes, but PHP processes the PHP file in a much lower-level system, which is considerably faster than manually parsing it in a higher-level one.